# Is it possible to know when a Ruby class has finished chaining methods?

Tags: ruby, method-chaining

I'm trying to determine if it is possible in Ruby to determine when a chain of methods has finished being called.

Consider that I have a class which retrieves information from a database. I often just want to call an instance of the class to access *all* the included data, but in many situations I chain additional methods which apply filters etc. Currently the actual data retrieval is performed by a method which is always called last, like so:

```rb
all_data = data_retriever.run
filtered_data = data_retriever.condition({k1: v1}).run
filtered_data = data_retriever.condition({k1: v1}).condition({k2: v2}).run
```

This works fine, but I can't help but think that Ruby may have a way to do this without tacking a method like `.run` on the end of every usage. Is it possible for my class to "know" when I've finished chaining methods? Such as a hook that executes after all the chained methods are called?

```rb
class DataRetriever 
  @conditions = {}
  def initialize()
  end
 
  def condition(condition_hash)
    @conditions << condition_hash
  end

  #...

  def after_chains
    # run the data retrieval code using the contents of @conditions
  end
end
```

Comment: The closest you can get is to run your code in a Proc, lambda, or block and then trigger your behavior when it returns. In other words, encapsulate your method calls and then do something with the result, notify an observer, or trigger a callback of some kind. From a Ruby perspective, though, almost everything but keywords and literals are just method calls or expressions, so it's up to you to decide when something is "done."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for my class to "know" when I've finished chaining methods?

No, chaining the methods is equivalent to calling them one after another. The receiver cannot distinguish the call style. And this is actually good, consider the following:

```
retriever = data_retriever.condition({k1: v1})
retriever.condition({k2: v2}) if something
retriever.condition({k3: v3}) if something_else
data = retriever.run
```

In the above example, you probably wouldn't want the first line to already trigger the data retrieval.

> Ruby may have a way to do this without tacking a method like `.run` on the end of every usage

Instead of `run`, you could use a more subtle entry point to trigger the execution, e.g. `each` which is Ruby's default enumeration method:

```
data = data_retriever.condition({k1: v1})

data.each do |entry|
  # ...
end
```

Under the hood: (there are various ways to implement this)

```
class DataRetriever
  def run
    @data = # retrieve actual data
  end

  def each(&block)
    run unless @data
    
    @data.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Just make sure to invalidate `@data` when more conditions are added (or alternatively `freeze` the object after `run`).

You could even call `each` from `inspect`: (you might want to abbreviate long data)

```
class DataRetriever
  def inspect
    "#<DataRetriever data=#{each.to_a.inspect}>"
  end
end
```

In irb:

```
filtered_data = DataRetriever.new.condition({k1: v1})
#=> #<DataRetriever data=[1, 2, 3]>
```

Comment: I would further the "subtle" comment with a block context whereby conditions are set inside the block. Simply yielding `self` to the block would be sufficient but `instance_eval` is a practical option too. `run` would then be triggered by the termination of the block execution. Alternately you could go with a `Rails` like mechanism of continuous "spawns" until data visibility/interactivity is required (which is hinted at in the `each` context provided here)

Comment: @Stefan That's a shame, I hoped ruby had something hidden in the chain execution code which would let you tell where a method was returning to. Oh well, thank you for your answer and suggestions